# How to disable all toggle buttons except one that clicked?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making an application using C# and WPF

I have 8 toggle buttons.

When I click one of the buttons others should be disabled so I can't  click it except one is activated.
When I click this button again others should be enabled

*Styles.xaml:*

```
<!--Toggle Button-->
<Style x:Key="ToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#535353"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="30"/>        
    <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderThickness="0">
                </Border>                    
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

*MainWindow.xaml:*

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="CategoryToggle1"
              Grid.Row="1"                      
              Style="{StaticResource ToggleButton}"
              Checked="ShowOptions"
              Unchecked="HideOptions" />
```

**How Can I achieve this by code and XAML?**

I want to do it like in this video:

[Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4zGp.jpg)

Comment: Sounds strange. Why won't you use RadioButtons?

Comment: @Clemens I think it is not possible to make radio buttons act like toggle buttons. I mean if a radio button will have two states. IsChecked and UnChecked. But I don't have experience in WPF. I can use any button if it will work as buttons on video

Comment: I haven't looked at the video. It just sounds strange to me that you need to uncheck one Button before you can check another.

Comment: @Clemens it is comfortable for me to have all buttons disable before I UnCheck a toggle button. Can you show me any example or an example with radio buttons?

Comment: There are plenty on the internet. Basically, when one RadioButton in a group is checked, any other that was checked before is unchecked.

Comment: @Clemens it's not really RadioButtons, they look more like ``Expander`` actually, with only one `Expander` that could be expanded at a time.

Comment: @Corentin Pane Actually The application on the video is made with JavaFX by me and I used this code to do it: `group.getToggles().stream().map((toggle) -> (ToggleButton) toggle).forEach((b) -> {
        b.setDisable(false);
      });` as for `Expander` It is not expander it is just a Pane that is resized with animation:)

Comment: I 'm learning C# and WPF only now and I don't know how to make this simple method from Java in C# that checks all buttons and disable it except the one is activated

Comment: You could do the same in code behind, hook-up to all click events and disable all others when one is clicked. That would be a quick work-around if you want to use toggle buttons.

Comment: @Corentin Pane, It really doesn't matter for me what type of button it will be. I just want to make the same thing that on the video)

Comment: Re template a radio button. Wpf controls are lookless. Or. Use a listbox for all those options and use isselected to drive the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for comments guys, I found another solution.

*MainWindow.XAML:*

```
 <RadioButton x:Name="CategoryToggle1"
                  Grid.Row="1" 
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 Style="{StaticResource RadioButton}"
                 GroupName="ToggleButtonsGroup"
                 Checked="OpenOptions"
                 Unchecked="HideOptions"/>
```

*Styles.xaml:*

```
<!--Radio Button-->
<Style TargetType="RadioButton"
       x:Key="RadioButton"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!--Toggle Button-->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#535353" />        
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderThickness="0">
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter  Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="true">
                        <Setter  Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

*MainWindow.cs:*

```
private void OpenOptions(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
RadioButton radioButton = sender as RadioButton;
        radioButton.IsChecked = true;

        //Disable all option buttons except one that active
        MyGrid.Children.OfType<RadioButton>().Where(rb => rb != radioButton && 
    rb.GroupName == radioButton.GroupName).ToList().ForEach(rb => rb.IsEnabled = false);
}

    private void HideOptions(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton radioButton = sender as RadioButton;

        MyGrid.Children.OfType<RadioButton>().Where(rb => rb.GroupName == 
     radioButton.GroupName).ToList().ForEach(rb => rb.IsEnabled = true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using `Click` events of each `ToggleButton`**

One way you could do it is by giving a name to all your `ToggleButtons`, hook-up to their `Click` event and manually uncheck others in the code-behind:

*XAML*

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="15"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ToggleButton x:Name="button1" Content="Button 1" Click="button1_Click"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 1"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ToggleButton x:Name="button2" Content="Button 2" Click="button2_Click"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 2"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ToggleButton x:Name="button3" Content="Button 3" Click="button3_Click"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Line 3"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

*Code-behind*

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    if (button1.IsChecked == true) {
        button2.IsChecked = false;
        button3.IsChecked = false;
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    if (button2.IsChecked == true) {
        button1.IsChecked = false;
        button3.IsChecked = false;
    }
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    if (button3.IsChecked == true) {
        button1.IsChecked = false;
        button2.IsChecked = false;
    }
}
```

This method is tedious, error-prone, requires code-behind and is not very scalable.

**Binding `IsChecked` properties to a collection of `bool` with one `true` at a time.**

Another way you could go (still by using code-behind) is to define a collection of boolean values and bind each `ToggleButton.IsChecked` on one of the `bool` in the collection, and ensure that the collection only contains at most one `true` at a time:

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ToggleButton x:Name="button1" Content="Button 1" IsChecked="{Binding [0]}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Line 1"/>
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ToggleButton x:Name="button2" Content="Button 2" IsChecked="{Binding [1]}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Line 2"/>
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ToggleButton x:Name="button3" Content="Button 3" IsChecked="{Binding [2]}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Line 3"/>
</StackPanel>
```

*Code-behind*

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        ObservableCollection<bool> states = new ObservableCollection<bool> { false, false, false };
        states.CollectionChanged += States_CollectionChanged;
        DataContext = states;
    }

    private void States_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
        var collection = sender as ObservableCollection<bool>;
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace) {
            if ((bool)e.NewItems[0]) {
                for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++) {
                    if (e.NewStartingIndex != i) {
                        collection[i] = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Again, this uses code-behind and not the view model but at least it is easier to add rows.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you need is very specific.

I don't know how, but i got here trying to make a toggle button behave like a radio button. Your answer was enlightning.

For what it's worth, here's how you would do that :

Resource :

```
<Style x:Key='RadioToggle' TargetType='RadioButton'
       BasedOn='{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}' />
```

Control :

```
<RadioButton Content='RadioToggle1' IsChecked='True' 
             Style='{StaticResource RadioToggle}' 
             GroupName="RadioToggleGroup" />
<RadioButton Content='RadioToggle2' 
             Style='{StaticResource RadioToggle}'
             GroupName="RadioToggleGroup" />
<RadioButton Content='RadioToggle3'
             Style='{StaticResource RadioToggle}'
             GroupName="RadioToggleGroup" />
```